# How to change the name of virtual environment in conan?

Tags: conan

I am making a package for `cmake/3.10.2` and I want that whenever I do `conan install .` it should display `devenv` instead of `conanenv`. I don't want to manually change `activate.sh` file. Is there any way to do it from conan recipe. I am using `virtualenv` as generator.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, the name is hard-coded, you can check it on the [code](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/blob/d8b859a04697e5111b65c35d6e73853a53e0ab23/conans/client/generators/virtualenv.py#L13).

However, you could open an [issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues) requesting for such feature.

Regards!

Comment: I was able to do it by setting the path in pacakage reciepe `self.env_info.PS1 = (devenv)+"$OLD_PS1"` in

Comment: This is an workaround, not the properly way. If you want to change the environment name correctly, open an issue. Regards!